# Debugging with local instance and authentication cookies

Tags: cookies, dns, localhost, instance, local

So, I've recently taken over the front-end of a project in which the previous front-end developer always did his debugging with a localhost instance connecting to a remote staging back-end.

Right now we are improving some security issues and are using CSRF tokens.

For each POST,PUT,DELETE request, I'm first `GET`ting a csrf endpoint, which sets a JSESSIONID HttpOnly cookie and returns a CSRF token in the response body. For the subsequent request the CSRF token goes into the request header and the cookie of course gets sent automatically of course.

Now,.. my code works fine deployed on the remote staging front-end. But, this new functionality has totally prevented me from debugging with a local instance, because the cookie wont work when I `GET` the CSRF token from localhost, because this is a different domain of course.
This requires me to deploy every single change of code to the staging front end. Very uncomfortable workflow when performing the usual trial-and-error fix.

Adding the remote as a localhost alias to my hosts file also doesn't work, because this routes all my requests to the remote to my own machine, which doesn't run a local instance of the remote.

I would've thought there would be a Chrome extension or something like that for problems like these, but since I couldn't find any I wondered if I'm missing a very obvious point here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that this was a really general issue:

set `withCredentials` to `true` for the request to the remote and use a chrome plugin to overwrite the response headers to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```